# Is there any expression for explaining that someone justifies his wrongdoings by mentioning the others'?

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

Is there any expression for explaining that someone justifies his wrongdoings by mentioning the others'?
For example, when someones says that because everyone cheats, I also can cheat.

Answer (score 1):

*shifting the blame* or plain *denial*. The specific example would be a matter of psychology, the fallacy likely has a fitting name.

Answer (score 1):

A term that has recently entered the mainstream is "Whataboutism."

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whataboutism